# Can't send POST request using browser

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, spring-mvc, post

I am working on an application using Spring Boot MVC and I have a login page and whenever I input data on the forms using chrome my browser doesn't redirect me to the page I've specified in my Controler class but instead It sends a GET request where it should be sending a POST request. This is my controller class

```java
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public class loginController {
        private final AuthService authService;
    
        public loginController(AuthService authService) {
            this.authService = authService;
        }
    
        @GetMapping
        public String returnLogIn() {
            return "login";
        }
    
        @PostMapping
        public String login(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    
            User user = null;
            try {
                user = this.authService.login(username, password);
                model.addAttribute("User", user);
                request.getSession().setAttribute("user",user);
                return "redirect:/home";
            } catch (InvalidArgumentsException exception) {
    
                model.addAttribute("hasError", true);
                model.addAttribute("error", exception.getMessage());
                return "login";
            }
        }
    }
```

As you see if the login is successful then I should be redirected to the home page but It doesn't happen I get redirected to the login page again and all that changes is the URL in it the parameters I've given are appended. But when I use POSTMAN everything works just fine a POST request is sent and I get redirected to the /home page just like I've specified it in my Controller class. But I don't know why this wont happen when I use chrome. Having to use POSTMAN everytime I do a small change is really time-consuming. Also this is the HTML form

```html
<form id="form-id" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/login}">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <input  type="text" class="form-control" 
       name="username" id="username"  
       aria-describedby="emailHelp"
       placeholder="User Name">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <!-- TODO use hasError set it in the model -->
  <div th:if="${hasError}">
    <span class="error text-danger" th:text="${error}"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-color px-5 mb-5 w-100 btn btn-dark" >Login</button></div>
</form>
```

I don't think there is something wrong with my code since everything works fine when I use POSTMAN but I really don't know why It wont work when I use my browser. Javascript is enabled in my browser I really don't know what seems to be the issue. I also tried mapping the POST request to a different URL but still I get the same issue.
I really don't know what seems to be the issue

As mentioned I can't send POST request using chrome but everything works fine with POSTMAN

Comment: what is the answer in postman? 302?

Comment: @VladimirShefer 200 
Everything works fine in postman I can login and I get redirected to the main page like I've specified in my controller class but with Chrome it wont work when  I input the parameters and click the button the browser sends a GET request where it should be sending a POST request

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `th:method="POST"` with  `method="POST"`
Also, did you get InvalidArgumentsException trying with Chrome?

Comment: I've tried that nothing changed, Nope I don't, I put in users that I've created still nothing happens the same happens when I put in a wrong password I don't get the exception all I get is a GET request which redirects me to the login page again and in the URL I can see the parameters are there
ex: http://localhost:9092/login?username=Enis&password=enis